# Http with www is not directing to htpps www

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

Now http with www urls are not redirecting to https://www. Http url(without www) are redirecting to https://www
From http:// without www is properly redirecting to https://www. But http with www is not redirecting to https www
Below is my htaccess code:

```
<Files ~ "\.log$"> 
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
+FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA}                 !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:FORWARDED}           !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:USERAGENT_VIA}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_FOR}     !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:PROXY_CONNECTION}    !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:XPROXY_CONNECTION}   !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_CLIENT_IP}      !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} anonymous [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.shtml
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/themes/default/(.*)
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/themes/PARENT_THEME/$2 -f
#RewriteRule ^themes/([^/]+)/(.*)$ themes/PARENT_THEME/$2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^themes/([^/]+)/(.*)$ themes/default/$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*\.js) combine.php?type=javascript&files=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php [L]
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
AuthUserFile "/home/garry/.htpasswds/public_html/www.exam.com/passwd"
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I see you explicitly redirecting to HTTPS in one single place there - and that is based on the condition that the host name did not start with `www.`, so for any `http://www.example.com/…` URLs, this should have no effect to begin with.

Comment: Quite hard to tell what is actually going on here though, due to how chaotic this is, with the exceptions for `.well-known` thrown in all over the place. I doubt that you need to be that specific about sub-paths of that folder to begin with, so just having one general exception for everything under `.well-known/` should probably do. It might make the most sense if you handled this at the very top - _one_ RewriteRule that simply does nothing, if the requested URL path starts with `.well-known/`, and uses the `[L]` flag to prevent anything else from happening in that case.

Comment: thank you let me try it

Comment: i removed some junk code. issue is still same

Comment: As 04FS has already stated above, there's nothing in the `.htaccess` file you've posted that would trigger the redirect you describe. Please confirm that the undesirable redirect is for the `www.example.com` host and not `example.com`?

Comment: its www.example.com

Comment: I don't understand, what your problem is.

Comment: all my old http.www.example.com links are redirected to https .www.example.com homepage, not to the specific url links. For   example http:/ / www.example.com/about.html should direct to https:// www.example.com/about.html but instead it goes to https:// www.example.com

Comment: The problematic redirect would seem to be in your PHP code. (?)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion i am looking on it with my very limited knowledge

Comment: redirect to https domain page itself is solved but now all the old http links are not redirecting they stays the same.

Comment: Now http://www urls are not redirecting to https://www. Without www http:// url are redirecting to https://www but not https://www.. one

Comment: finally it all work out thank you guys for support